# Need help inserting data into Postgres tables

Tags: postgresql

I get an error trying to insert data into my tables ... but I don't know why?
Syntax is correct.

```
column "population" is of type integer but expression is of type record
```

[image: original error message]

```
create table states(name varchar(25), population int );
create table countries(name varchar(25), population int );
insert into states values (('tn',54945),('ap',2308));
select name from states;
insert into countries values (('india',3022),('america',30902));
select * from countries;
```

Comment: Please don't post links to paintings of text. Post the error message text itself.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't post the sql code that causes this error. Also include the definitions of the involved tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are extra parentheses around the tuples of values to insert, which turns the whole thing to a single record of records.

Instead:

```
insert into countries(name, population) values ('india',3022),('america',30902);
```